# Basic Authentication and WSGI do not work together

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, flask, basic-authentication

It's my first experience deploying a Flask application. I would like to have basic authentication, so the config file for my virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName 144.245.121.90
            ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myApp/myapp.wsgi
            <Location />
                    AuthType Basic
                    AuthName "restricted"
                    AuthBasicProvider file
                    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                    Require valid-user
            </Location></VirtualHost>
```

But It does not work for me, I tried a dozen different formats. Can someone kindly give me a hint on what I should do to make it work?

Comment: What does "does not work for me" mean? It shows the page without asking for a password, or it asks for a password and you can't log in? Some information on the unwanted behaviour would be nice.

Comment: It shows the page without asking the password